# Integration test with DBUnit SpringFramework java

Tags: java, spring

I am trying to write a integration test using DBUnit and SpringFramework. I have copied the code that i have write but i have problem with in-memory database connection. I have also copied the stack trace.

```
  @RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
    @ContextConfiguration
    @Transactional
    @TestExecutionListeners({ DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.class, DirtiesContextTestExecutionListener.class,
            TransactionalTestExecutionListener.class, DbUnitTestExecutionListener.class })
    @DatabaseSetup(type = DatabaseOperation.CLEAN_INSERT, value = "login.xml")
    public class LoginControllerTest {

        private MockMvc mockMvc;

        @Before
        public void setUp() {
            mockMvc = MockMvcBuilders.xmlConfigSetup("applicationContext.xml").build();
        }

        @Test
        @ExpectedDatabase("login.xml")
        public void testShowForm() throws Exception {
            mockMvc.perform(get("/login")).andExpect(status().isOk()).andExpect(view().name("/login"))
                    .andExpect(forwardedUrl("/WebContent/j/login.jsp"))
                    .andExpect(model().attribute("form", hasProperty("id", nullValue())))
                    .andExpect(model().attribute("form", hasProperty("email", isEmptyOrNullString())))
                    .andExpect(model().attribute("form", hasProperty("username", isEmptyOrNullString())))
                    .andExpect(model().attribute("form", hasProperty("hostname", isEmptyOrNullString())))
                    .andExpect(model().attribute("form", hasProperty("pass", isEmptyOrNullString())));
        }
    }
```

**login.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<dataset>
    <person id="1" email="qwerty@asdf.com" username="qwerty"
        hostname="asdf.com" pass="password1234" />

    <person id="2" email="zxcvb@asdf.com" username="zxcvb"
        hostname="asdf.com" pass="password1234" />
</dataset>
```

**Stack Trace**

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to find a DB Unit database connection, missing one the following beans: [dbUnitDatabaseConnection, dataSource]
    at com.github.springtestdbunit.DbUnitTestExecutionListener.getDatabaseConnectionUsingCommonBeanNames(DbUnitTestExecutionListener.java:111)
    at com.github.springtestdbunit.DbUnitTestExecutionListener.prepareTestInstance(DbUnitTestExecutionListener.java:94)
    at org.springframework.test.context.TestContextManager.prepareTestInstance(TestContextManager.java:231)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.createTest(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:95)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.invokeTestMethod(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:139)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.JUnit4ClassRunner.runMethods(JUnit4ClassRunner.java:51)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.JUnit4ClassRunner$1.run(JUnit4ClassRunner.java:44)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.ClassRoadie.runUnprotected(ClassRoadie.java:27)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.ClassRoadie.runProtected(ClassRoadie.java:37)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.JUnit4ClassRunner.run(JUnit4ClassRunner.java:42)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:86)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:459)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:675)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:382)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:192)
```

Answer (score 1):

If you already configured the `transactionManager` and `dataSource`, most probably the problem is that the configuration file is not found in the location you've given.

If it is located in the classpath, you should put the `classpath:` prefix to the config location string.

```
mockMvc = MockMvcBuilders.xmlConfigSetup("classpath:applicationContext.xml").build();
```